# WordPress fresh installation did not update default plugin and themes to latest version

Tags: wordpress

I tried to install `WordPress` latest version, which is 5.4.2, and after finishing the installation, I have logged in to the Admin Pannel/Dashboard and found that a couple of default themes and plugins did not update to the latest version.

Is it by default `WordPress` did not updated it to the latest version?

[image: WordPress Dashboard]

Comment: It's possible that the WP bundle included plugins that have been updated after the bundle was released

Comment: Just simply click on the updates link and update them and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundled plugins and themes will be the version that they were when that version of WordPress is released. New versions of WordPress aren’t created when updates are released for the bundled plugins and themes. They’ll just be rolled into the next version of WordPress. credit to Jacob Peattie for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress automatically install their default theme's newest version (for now, it's TwentyTwenty). If you already use the older version of WordPress then you update WordPress core, it doesn't update your themes or plugins, you have to update it by yourself.

Comment: here is the link where i download wordpress 
https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
 i tried 3rd time already but it still give me the same.
i need to update it manually..

Comment: You need to make sure your site is completely fresh. If it's a running site, and you update it, then your installed plugins and themes won't be updated manually. WordPress newest version only comes with their default themes and plugins newest version.